# How to modify some options for Matrix from existing type to create a new Matrix type in template programming?

Tags: c++, eigen

For example, assuming we have a matrix type `T`, can we create a new type that has only 1 cols like `Matrix<..., ..., 1 ,...>` and keep other options exactly the same in type `T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I give following solution:

```
template<typename T1>
auto fun(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T1>& _X)
{
    using T = typename T1::PlainObject;
    using T2 = Eigen::Matrix<typename  T::Scalar,
        T::RowsAtCompileTime, T::ColsAtCompileTime,
        T::Options, T::MaxRowsAtCompileTime, T::MaxColsAtCompileTime>;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T2, T>)
    {
        std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
    }
    return T();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, this should be the simplest form:

```
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<...>; // your type
using Vector = typename Matrix::ColXpr::PlainObject;
```